# Despite using 'fillable' and checking all variables, my create method in the controller is not saving input to model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to save some data to my model using a form and my controller.

The form looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <h1>Assign days to event</h1>

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'days')) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('event_name', 'Event Name') }}                
            {{ Form::select('event_name', $events, null) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('day_number', 'Number of Days') }}                
            {{ Form::text('day_number', Input::old('day_number'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>

        {{ Form::submit('Assign!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}

    </div>
</body>
```

My Create/Store functions in my Controller looks like this:

```
namespace StrawDogBuilder\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use View;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use StrawDogBuilder\Day;
use StrawDogBuilder\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function create()
{
    $events = Event::pluck('id');
    return View::make('days.create')
        ->with('events', $events);
}


public function store()
{
    $rules = array(
        'event_id'  =>  'required',


        'day_number'    =>  'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('days/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } 
        else {
            $day = new day;
            $day->event_id  = Input::get('event_name');
            $day->day_number  = Input::get('day_number');
            $day->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'You have assigned this event a number of days');
            return Redirect::to('days');
    }
}
```

And my Model looks like this

```
class Day extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','event_name','day_number'];

public function mods() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Mod');
}

// Get the Event this day is attributed to
public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
}
}
```

The form is created without errors, however when I add values to the fields and hit 'Assign!' it will stay on the same page and will not indicate if it has done anything. Checking the table shows that it hasn't saved the data.

Am I missing something that causes the form to save the data via the controller, and if so what could it be?

Comment: Isnt your class Day and not day. And did you imported the model in your controller?

Comment: @Exprator - Classes are case insensitive, but I would agree that using `Day` would make it easier to understand. @stntmnky - Can you please provide more detail about the model file like the namespace and any `use` statements?

Comment: Fixed day to Day and I have imported the model but that doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Comment: Yeahknow that but still for us to understand better you should follow few rules

Comment: Is the form even using POST? because u haven't mentioned type. So generally it will take GET Request. Fix it in your form

Comment: Also, I haven't explicitly had to use POST or GET for another form I created that worked so I'm not sure why the same code I've used here isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all revised your form as

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'days.store']) !!}
```

Then in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
        array(
            'event_id'  =>  'required',
            'day_number'    =>  'required',
        )
    );

    $day = new Day;
    $day->event_id  = $request->event_name;
    $day->day_number  = $request->day_number;
    $day->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'You have assigned this event a number of days');
    return redirect()->route('days');
}
```

Comment: please try to `return response()->json($request);` at the start of the controller to check if all inputs are being passed correctly